# Beforeskip of @startsection has no effect

Tags: spacing, sectioning, section-titles

Consider the following MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\catcode`@=11
\renewcommand\section{%
\@startsection{section}%
  {1} %Level
  {\z@} %Indent
  {2cm} %Beforeskip, changed
  {4ex} %Afterskip, changed
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}} %Style
\catcode`@=12
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\section{Bar}
asdf
\end{document}
```

I don't see any difference when changing the "Beforeskip" argument of `\@startsection`.

Any explanation about it?

[image]

Comment: skips at top of page are dropped try `foobar \section{foo}`

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question.

Comment: you see a difference if you have text before, as it is you are only seeing the afterskip from the chapter head,

Comment: by design if one heading follows another you only get the afterskip of the first

Comment: `\vspace*{3cm}\section{,,,,}` you need the `*` form for same reason a  normal vspace is dropped at a page break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skips at the start of the page are dropped, and
by design if one heading follows another you only get the afterskip of the first, so to see the difference here you need some normal text before the `\section`.